# Conflict Elasticsearch with Play 2.5.14

Tags: java, elasticsearch, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5

I am trying to integrate Elasticksearch with Playframework  `"org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "5.5.1"
play 2.5.14
elasticsearch 5.5.1`

but it crashes in runtime.

`[CompletionException: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{oJHwmd1zRZO70x-7NVClqw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]]`

Help me, please.   Otherwise there will be blood

Answer (score 0):

this is not a runtime crash at all. The transport client tells you that it could not find any node available under localhost, port 9300. Is Elasticsearch running somewhere else?

Comment: I have made the same console application on Maven and it works quite cool. THat is why i consider it as a dependency problem. So maybe you can give me some advice to solve it?

Comment: it is not a dependency problem (if it was, you would not see the above message). When the transport node client is started, it tries to reach the configured elasticsearch nodes (localhost:9300 by default), and if it cannot reach it, the above error message occurs. Are you sure you configured the correct cluster name? Have you checked the server elasticsearch logs, if a connection came in? Can you increase the logging of the transport client?

Answer (score 0):

There's a version conflict between the underlying netty play brings (4.0.x) and elasticsearch (4.1.x)

see here for some [workarounds](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/issues/666)